# Java. Как использовать переменные других Activity?

Tags: java, android, переменные

Пишу приложение под android. У меня есть 3 класса: `MainActivity`, `SecondActivity`, `FinalActivity`.
В классе FinalActivity мне нужно использовать переменную `firstVar` из класса MainActivity и переменную `secondVar` из класса secondActivity.

Напишите пожалуйста как мне это сделать.

Comment: лучше передавать как параметр в другую активность (так и ищите информации полно)

Answer (score 2):

**Что такое Activity?** Activity это отдельный экран, с которым взаимодействует пользователь. Этот экран может вести на множество других экранов. На этот экран так же можно попасть с множества других мест.

Теперь представим ситуацию. У вас есть активити **A** и активити **В**. Флоу такой, пользователю показывается экран **A** и при нажатии на кнопку он попадает на экран **В**. Вы решили что в активити В нужна какая-то переменная из активити **A**. Вы сделали ее public, получили к ней доступ и успешно ее используете.

Через неделю к вам приходит заказчик и говорит, я хочу сделать deeplink который будет вести пользователя сразу на активити **В**, он там совершит какие-то действия и приложения закроется или пойдет по какому-то другому флоу. Вам придется подымать активити **A** для того чтоб работала активити **В**.

А потом этот же заказчик попросит вас вообще перенести кнопку перехода из активити **A** в активити **В** в активти **С** (**С** открывает **В**). И вам придется еще лезть в какие-то переменные и переносить их и изменять ваш код.

**Вывод.** Экраны должны быть максимально независимы друг от друга. В идеале они не должны знать ничего друг о друге, максимум это то как открыть другую активити. Все! Ни о каких методах или переменных они знать не должны!

Как быть если надо из активити **A** передать какие-то параметры в активити **В**? Решений много:

- синглтон который живет на протяжении всего приложения и никак не связан на жизненный цикл Активити.
- база данных. Активти **A** передает в активити **В** только id вашего объекта и активити В сама его открывает.
- Presenter-ы и ViewModel-и.

В общем любая другая сущность которая живет отдельно от активити и чья зона ответственности **"Хранить данные"**

Answer (score 0):

Я бы советовал использовать отдельный класс в котором будет необходимая вам переменная. Такие классы используют паттерн синглтона и работает это так. Создаем класс-синглтон:

```
public class Single {

    private static final Single INSTANCE = new Single();

    private Single(){}


    public static Single getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

дальше добавляем переменную в этот класс, например такую:

```
String test = "";
```

Дальше в нужной вам активности сетим переменной значение:

```
Single().getInstance().test = "some_data"
```

и дальше там где вам нужно можно вытащить эту переменную:

```
Single().getInstance().test
```

Вот есть интересные статьи по данному вопросу [1](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/singleton/java/example) и [2](https://habr.com/ru/post/129494/).